How to avoid documentation duplication in CG/HLSL?
Let's say we have few function overrides in CG/HLSL, and this functions need some big and almost the same documentation, so how to get it for each override without repeating the same text?
/**
* Long general documentation
*/
int do() {...}

/**
* Long general documentation
* @param Value parameter specific documentation
*/
int do(int value) {...}

From the solution I expect having docs in one place and be able to see them properly rendered by hovering the mouse on the any function name (in our case any do overrides) in IDEs like Rider. Eg. just comments like // see do() function for more info aren't what I expect.
I tried keywords like @ref, @see, @copydoc, @copybrief and many others, nothing is rendered as expected and don't allow to jump to function where documentation is defined. Maybe the problem is related to my software, just for case, I'm using Unity 2022.3, Rider 2024.2 and writting in CGPROGRAM, .gcinc.
TL;TD: What is the alternative to c# inheritdoc in CG/HLSL?

The workaround I came up so far is moving common documentation to separate variables and do sort of referring to it.
/**
* Long general documentation
* @related do
*/
int GeneralDoFunctionDocumentation


/** @related GeneralDoFunctionDocumentation */
int do() {...}

/**
* @related GeneralDoFunctionDocumentation
* @param Value parameter specific documentation
*/
int do(int value) {...}

This approach allows (at least in Rider) to jump to the variable definition and see the docs by hovering the mouse on it, but it's still inconvenient in many cases.
